# Javascript random countdown - how to repeat same time multiple times on same page

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a random countdown script, as per below:

Here is the Javascript:

```
   <script>

var timer;
function startCount()
{
    timer = setInterval(count, 1000); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}
function count()
{
    var do_wait = Math.ceil(4*Math.random());
    if (do_wait == 4) {
        var rand_no = Math.ceil(4*Math.random()); // 9 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 9.
        var el = document.getElementById('counter');
        var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
        var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
        if (newNumber > 3) {
            el.innerHTML = newNumber;
        } else {
            el.innerHTML = '<font color="white">3</font>';  // This message is displayed when the counter reaches zero.
        }
    }
}
startCount();

</script>
```

Here is how I am calling it in HTML

```
<span style="color:white;" id="counter">50</span>
```

I want to be able to display the ID "counter" multiple times on the page with the same countdown number. The problem is each time I display ID "counter" it has a different countdown number.

Comment: Every `id` on a page must be unique. You should try using `class="counter"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change 'id' for 'name' so I do not have the same id multiple times in my document. I've made a few changes in your code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script>

var timer;
function startCount()
{
    timer = setInterval(count, 1000); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}
function count()
{
    var do_wait = Math.ceil(4*Math.random());
    if (do_wait == 4) {
        var rand_no = Math.ceil(4*Math.random()); // 9 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 9.
        var els = document.getElementsByName('counter');
    for(var i = 0 ; i < els.length ; i++) {
          var currentNumber = parseFloat(els[i].innerHTML);
          var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
          if (newNumber > 3) {
            els[i].innerHTML = newNumber;
          } else {
            els[i].innerHTML = '<font color="white">3</font>';  // This message is displayed when the counter reaches zero.
          }
        }
    }
}
startCount();

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <span style="color:white;" name="counter">50</span>

    <span style="color:white;" name="counter">50</span>

    <span style="color:white;" name="counter">50</span>

    <span style="color:white;" name="counter">50</span>
</body>
```

I'm now using counter as values for **name** attributes and **document.getElementsByName()** to read those array of names.
BTW, I tested in Chrome.